# mvn package (build failure) flexmojos - how do I get my flash player in the right path

Tags: flexmojos

build failure says it cant find my flash player but the flash player is installed
I even put it in my Path variable
right here i was just trying to run mvn package
also i have maven installed in my eclipse SDK but i cant get it to pop up
but for the most part i'm just worried about this problem right here
any Suggestions?

```
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3\my-app\jason\MavenFlexJavaApp>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MavenFlexJavaApp Flex 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ MavenFlexJ
avaApp ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.1-beta:compile-swf (default-compile-swf) @ M
avenFlexJavaApp ---
[INFO] Flexmojos 4.1-beta
[INFO] Apache License - Version 2.0 (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
[WARNING] No themes are explicitly defined in the <theme> section or in any scop
e="theme" dependencies. Flexmojos is now attempting to figure out which themes t
o include. (to avoid this warning you should explicitly state your theme depende
ncies      [WARNING] Adding spark.css theme because spark.swc was included               asa          dependency
[INFO] Writing configuration dump to C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3\my-app\
jason\MavenFlexJavaApp\target\MavenFlexJavaApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-configs.xml
[INFO] C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3\my-app\jason\MavenFlexJavaApp\target\
MavenFlexJavaApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.swf (570344 bytes)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ Ma
venFlexJavaApp ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3\m
y-app\jason\MavenFlexJavaApp\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.1-beta:test-compile (default-test-compile) @
MavenFlexJavaApp ---
[INFO] Flexmojos 4.1-beta
[INFO] Apache License - Version 2.0 (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
[INFO] Compiling test class: [org.JasonThomas.ShadowInnovations.TestApp]
[WARNING] No themes are explicitly defined in the <theme> section or in any scop
e="theme" dependencies. Flexmojos is now attempting to figure out which themes t
o include. (to avoid this warning you should explicitly state your theme depende
ncies)
[WARNING] Adding spark.css theme because spark.swc was included as a dependency
[INFO] Writing configuration dump to C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3\my-app\
jason\MavenFlexJavaApp\target\test-classes\TestRunner-configs.xml
[INFO] C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3\my-app\jason\MavenFlexJavaApp\target\
test-classes\TestRunner.swf (960078 bytes)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.1-beta:test-run (default-test-run) @ MavenFl
exJavaApp ---
[INFO] Flexmojos 4.1-beta
[INFO] Apache License - Version 2.0 (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
[INFO] Running tests C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3\my-app\jason\MavenFlexJ
avaApp\target\test-classes\TestRunner.swf
[WARNING] [LAUNCHER] Using regular flashplayer tests
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.588s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Dec 18 21:20:58 CST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/342M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.1
-beta:test-run (default-test-run) on project MavenFlexJavaApp: Failed to launch
Flash Player. Probably java was not able to find flashplayer.
[ERROR] Make sure flashplayer is available on PATH
[ERROR] or use -DflashPlayer.command=${flashplayer executable}
[ERROR] Read more at: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/Running+unit+t
ests: Cannot run program "flashplayer": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot
find the file specified
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
`enter code here`C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3\my-app\jason\MavenFlexJavaApp>
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually simply rename the debug player "flashplayer.exe" and make sure the directory containing it is in my systems Path ... nothing more to it.

Answer (score 0):

You must rename flashplayer_10_sa_debug.exe to FlashPlayer.exe